# Ref from Dropdown.Button (antd)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

How can I get a ref to a Dropdown.Button (it is antd), when I set a ref to it, it returns a wrapper ?

```
 parent = null;
 parentRef = node => (this.parent = node);

render(){
 return (
 <Dropdown.Button
   ref={this.parentRef}
   overlay={menu}
   type="primary"
  >
     content
 </Dropdown.Button>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use reference API, `useRef` or `React.createRef`.

Refer to [`Refs and the DOM in React`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

```
class App extends React.Component {
  buttonRef = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.buttonRef);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Dropdown.Button ref={this.buttonRef} overlay={menu} type="primary">
        content
      </Dropdown.Button>
    );
  }
}
```

With hooks:

```
const App = () => {
  const buttonRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(buttonRef);
  }, []);

  return (
    <FlexBox>
      <Dropdown.Button ref={buttonRef} menu={menu}>
        drop down
      </Dropdown.Button>
    </FlexBox>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit Q-58498231-createRef]

Answer (score 0):

Hei,

Check out the [React.forwardRef()](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) here.

It's a function which you can wrap your 'child' component and it's specifically designed to make possible parent to have a reference to its children. Should solve your problem.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

you can by passing a cb function on the ref attrib:

```js
 parent = null;
 parentRef = ref => (this.parent = ref);

render(){
 return (
 <Dropdown.Button
   ref={parentRef}
   overlay={menu}
   type="primary"
  >
     content
 </Dropdown.Button>
 )
}
```

Or with useRef hook:

for functional components no classes

```js
const parentRef =React.useRef(null); 

return  (
   <Dropdown.Button
     ref={parentRef}
     overlay={menu}
     type="primary"
   >
     content
  </Dropdown.Button>
 )
```

Comment: What did you change here? (it also won't compile)

Comment: the attribute ref accepts a callback ` ref={(ref)=> this.parent = ref}` so when the component render it will assign the `this.parent` the component ref

Comment: What is the difference between OP's example?